# display image fetched from DB with Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm facing display images with Ajax. I don't know why it is not draw image in div tag.
it works when I put action in form tag and send it to find.php, but not working with Ajax

```
//display.php
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var str = 'img_arr='+ img_arr + '&img_url=' + img_url ;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
   document.getElementById("here").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}

 xmlhttp.open("GET","find.php?"+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
});
</scrpt>

<input type="text" id="img_url" name="img_url" value="google.com" />
<input type="text" id="img_arr" name="img_arr"  value="img.jpg" />
<div id="here"></div>

//find.php

<?
  $q = "...." 
  $r = @mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

  while($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
     echo ("<img src='button.png' style='margin-left:".$row['x_coord'].";margin-top:".$row['y_coord']."; position:absolute;' />");  
  }

?>
```

Comment: Can you post the form too? Also, are you sure the request returns the right content?

Comment: Check, what data find.php returns when you are manually submitting the ajax request through browser. Make sure, it is correct. Then check javascript with firebug.